# Would you ever want to start recording a macro from the quickfix window?

Tags: key-bindings, macro, quickfix

I'd like to map **`q`** to `:cclose` in the quickfix window, but I wonder if I'd be locking myself out of a world of wonderful macros by doing so.

Are there realistic scenarios where you'd want to be able to start recording a macro from the quickfix window? The only one I can think of is:

1. open the current error
2. do something
3. return to the quickfix window
4. move down to the next error

But I think it would be more convenient to open the current error, start the macro from that buffer, do something, and use `:cnext` to move to the next error. That way you don't have to jump back and forth between windows.

Is there a more compelling use-case for preserving the default **`q`** keybinding in the quickfix window?

Comment: It all depends on your workflow: as you said you can still use `:cnext` in your macro (which seems more efficient than going back to the quickfix window, change line and go to the next error). So you should remap `q` in the quickfix window, test this config for awhile and change it if you realize that it doesn't actually fit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not map `:cclose` to `<Leader>q`, if you want it as a shortcut? My guess is that you will inevitably need macros, and are boxing yourself into a corner by remapping `q`.

Comment: I just find `q` so much more satisfying on its own.

Comment: @ivan well you are going to limit your future access to recording macros. You could always map `q` itself to `<Leader>q`, so that macros are still easily accessible and then map `:cclose` to `q`.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the best compromise.